# Determine the ContentObserver

Tags: android, contentobserver

I have this content observer that is watching on the Call Log:

```
public class monitorCallLog extends ContentObserver{
    private static final String TAG = "monitorCallLog";
    public monitorCallLog(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() { 
        return false; 
    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
        Log.v(TAG, "[onChange] *** ENTER ***");
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        // Code goes in here to handle the job of tracking....
        Log.v(TAG, "[onChange] *** LEAVE ***");
    }
}
```

Now... how can I determine the nature of the change on this URI `content://call_log/calls`?

I want to check on it if a deletion has occurred on the said URI... but there is no way of knowing...this seems to apply on a query/delete/insert/update on said URI that triggers the `onChange` method....

any tips/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering an observer for each of the call Uris?

i.e. if you have 5 calls in the call log, register a content observer for each call Uri, perhaps having the observer initialised with the id of the call being observed.

That way when an individual call is deleted/updated, the delete method of the content provider will send a notification matching the individual call, rather than all calls.

I think this is a non-standard approach for lists from a cursor. I believe most uses of content observation will `requery()` the cursor.